# Serving a 404 without redirecting to /404/

Tags: .htaccess

I have a web application that serves urls such as...

```
http://domain.com/#!/this-is-a-parameter
```

I want to redirect from `http://domain.com/this-is-a-parameter` to my `!#` version. I know that htaccess can't redirect to hashes, so my question is:

How do I make htaccess serve a 404 with my js redirect code, without changing the url? All my attempts have resulted in redirection to 404.html, which strips out the necessary data to perform the redirect.

Comment: Why can't htaccess redirect to URLs with hashes in them? I don't see anything in Apache's documentation that says that. What you're attempting to do may be better suited to a mod_rewrite rule however..

Comment: When you try to redirect with a hash in the URL Apache encodes it, so you get `http://domain.com/%23!/parameter` and it goes into infinite loop hell.

Comment: I suspect thats only because %23!/ doesn't exist as a 'real file' or a defined location, not because it's impossible perse. However, I urge you to check out mod_rewrite.. It excels at handling needs like this.

Comment: Poking around I found this tutorial that might help you - http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/crazy-advanced-mod_rewrite-tutorial.html#Emulating_ErrorDocuments_Mod_Rewrite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://domain.com/#!/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

You need the `NE` so that the hash doesn't get encoded.